# Tkinter Problem for Converting IntVar to int

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was making a "Date Calculator" GUI using Tkinter, In which if a person enter today's date and want to know the date after certain days from that date he can know that by this GUI, for example, if I enter Date= 2019-04-05  and Skip=2 Days then it should return 2019-04-07 as the answer in the Console. But there is an error I am getting that the Year 0 is out of range please have a look at the code

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *
pydi=Tk()
pydi.geometry("720x120")

#Function
def Harsh():
    Date=datetime.date(y,m,d)
    Next=datetime.timedelta(f)
    New=Date+Next
    print(New)

#Label With Grid Packing (One liner)
Year=Label(pydi,text="Enter The Year").grid(row=1,column=1)
Month=Label(pydi,text="Enter The Month").grid(row=2,column=1)
Day=Label(pydi,text="Enter The Day").grid(row=3,column=1)
Skip=Label(pydi,text="Enter Skip Days").grid(row=4,column=1)

#Values
YearValue=IntVar()
MonthValue=IntVar()
DayValue=IntVar()
SkipValue=IntVar()

#Using Get to convert Tkinter IntVar to python int
y=YearValue.get()
m=MonthValue.get()
d=DayValue.get()
f=SkipValue.get()

#Entry Widget
YearEntry=Entry(pydi,textvariable=YearValue).grid(row=1,column=2)
MonthEntry=Entry(pydi,textvariable=MonthValue).grid(row=2,column=2)
DayEntry=Entry(pydi,textvariable=DayValue).grid(row=3,column=2)
SkipEntry=Entry(pydi,textvariable=SkipValue).grid(row=4,column=2)

#Button
Calculate=Button(pydi,bg="black",fg="white",text="Calculate",command=Harsh).grid(row=17,column=2)
pydi.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

use directly

```
def Harsh():
   #Date=datetime.date(y,m,d)
    Date = datetime.date(YearValue.get(), MonthValue.get(), DayValue.get())
    Next=datetime.timedelta(f)
    New=Date+Next
    print(New)
```

anyway the problem is show below,

> print(y,m,d) return 0,0,0

```
#Function
def Harsh():
    print(y,m,d)
    Date=datetime.date(y,m,d)
    Next=datetime.timedelta(f)
    New=Date+Next
    print(New)
```